# Ajax returning the success value as -1

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Below is the code i'm using. When ever i use to return some value , it's returning as -1. Please tell me where i made the mistake or guide me what's the pbm in the code!

Javascript:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j.ajax({
url:"<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
type:"POST",
data:"action=market_place_youtube_validator&id="+code,
success:function(data){$j("#loading").hide();$j("#mine").append(data);}
});
```

PHP (admin-ajax.php):

```
function market_place_youtube_validator()
{
echo "Yes Youtube is right";
}
```

Comment: Your code seams to have an error `google_video` in the query and `youtube` in the function name?

Comment: sorry i misspelling there.now i changed that. But it's returning the same!

Comment: Add a die statement in your ajax callback. It is correct to echo inside the callback but you need to either `die` or `exit` at the end of the callback. Eg. `die();` or `exit;` after your echo statement.

Comment: What's "returning"? Are you sure you're using the term "return" properly? Can you show us where `-1` is coming from?

Comment: Can you show us the entire admin-ajax.php?

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP (`echo "Yes Youtube is right";`) within javascript. To return a value you would need to do `return "Yes Youtube is right";`

Comment: even if i use return also it's returning -1 only!

Comment: No, he's posted PHP after Javascript and SO mangled them into one code block.

Comment: sorry. I didn't get you .. Could you please make me clearly??

Comment: Sorry the problem was fixed. In wordpress the ajax default returning the die() function. It's appending with the data what we producing custom.. So we have to use the die()  in our custom ajax function call.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your functions.php?

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_market_place_youtube_validator', 'youtube_validator');
```

Where wp_ajax_nopriv_[your action parameter name]

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j.ajax({
url:"<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
type:"POST",
data:"action=market_place_youtube_validator&id="+code,
success:function(data){$j("#loading").hide();$j("#mine").append(data);}
});
function youtube_validator()
{
echo "Yes Youtube is right";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call die or exit after the output is being echo to the browser to prevent returning value -1

Comment: Hi. It's already pointed out.Check the full story. Anyway thanks for your reply.